# Angular 8 - interceptor throwing error when a property in request.body is modified in PUT calls

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have an interceptor which is making some changes to the body of the `request.body` before parsing it to the server.

It is working fine if an HTTP POST call is being made. However, the same code breaks in HTTP PUT call.

In PUT call, all the properties of the body are becoming `read-only` and the error in the image is being displayed.

Here is the error image:

[image]

And here is the code screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your code?

Comment: have added now. please check! @Mohiuddinkhanromi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the above problem which worked for me:
I changed the runtimeChecks object values to false as ngRx was not allowing me to modify the object, which is what I was doing with PUT calls.

```
EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects]), 
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, 
    { metaReducers, 
        runtimeChecks: { 
            strictStateImmutability: false, 
            strictActionImmutability: false,
        } 
    }
),
```

Comment: another possible solution that worked for me was to serialize the JSON object and then do the modification on the values and again deserialize it. That way I reverted the immutability to true!

Answer (score 0):

You can store your read only data into a local variable

```
private modifyBody(body: any, property: string, value: string) {
    let tempProperty = property;
    let tempValue = value;
    let tempBody = body;
    tempBody[tempProperty] = tempValue.replace(/\s*$/, "");
    return tempBody;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. For POST calls the above code (mine and yours) is working fine.
No property of the model is read-only, it becomes read-only in PUT calls.

Comment: did you try by making a local variable for "property" and "value" too?? look through the changes I've made.

Comment: No, but identified the issue, I made the following changes in StoreModule metareducers

EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects]), 
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, 
    { metaReducers, 
        runtimeChecks: { 
            strictStateImmutability: false, 
            strictActionImmutability: false,
        } 
    }
),